# Retrieving the TOP 10 data with arithmetic operation

Tags: mysql, sql

**I want to retrieve the name of the user with the top 10 most voted post.**
the formula in calculating the votes should be `upvotes-downvotes`. *I also need to count the votes of that post.*

Here's my
**table user_info**

```
id       lname        fname
1        abc1         abc1
2        abc2         abc2
3        abc3         abc3
4        abc4         abc4
5        abc5         abc5
6        abc6         abc6
7        abc7         abc7
```

**table post**

```
post_id         post_message        user_id
1               sup                 1
2               good morning        2
3               hello               5
4               test                3
5               sample              4
```

**table vote**

```
vote_id      user_id       post_id              vote_type
1            1             1                    upvote
2            2             1                    upvote 
3            1             2                    downvote
4            1             2                    upvote
5            2             2                    downvote
6            3             1                    upvote
7            3             4                    upvote
8            4             4                    downvote
```

here's the query that I tried.

```
SELECT post_id, fname,lname,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote_type = 'upvote' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "upvotes", COUNT(CASE WHEN vote_type = 'downvote' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "downvotes"
FROM user_info 

LEFT JOIN post ON 
post.user_id = user_info.id

LEFT JOIN vote ON
post.user_id = user_info.id 

ORDER BY 'upvotes'- 'downvotes' // is this possible?
LIMIT 10
```

My desired output is something like this.

```
post_id      lname        fname     vote
1            abc1         abc1      3       // 3 upvotes
4            abc3         abc3      0       // 1upvote - 1 downvote
3            abc5         abc5      0       // no vote
5            abc4         abc4      0       // no vote
2            abc2         abc2     -1       // 1upvote - 2 downvotes
```

I don't know where I should put that column "vote" but it should be there in my query.

I created an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53fa1/1) for this

Comment: The sql fiddle is missing the post_id field in the vote table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5486/20)

```
select p.post_id,u.fname,u.lname,
case when sum(upvotes)+sum(downvotes) is null then 0
else sum(upvotes)+sum(downvotes) end as vote
 from post p left join
 (
 SELECT post_id,
 CASE WHEN vote_type = 'upvote' then 1 ELSE 0 END as "upvotes", 
 CASE WHEN vote_type = 'downvote' then -1 ELSE 0 END as "downvotes"
 FROM vote 
 ) t
 on p.post_id = t.post_id
 left join user_info u on p.user_id = u.id
 group by p.post_id
 order by vote desc, sum(upvotes) desc, sum(downvotes) desc
 limit 10;
```

Comment: are you getting the wrongresult? if so, could you post the results of the inner query?

Comment: wait i'm gonna make an sqlfiddle for this. but your query is giving the users' with no post 2 votes.

Comment: check the modified version..btw your sql fiddle had no info about `upvote` and `downvote`.. I added it.

Comment: I also forgot to put the post_id  in the vote table, i updated my fiddle. There's still something wrong with the vote counts bro. :(

Comment: It works now bro, thanks!! You're a huge help. I need this query for today.